# Communicating via two bash scripts

Tags: bash, scripts

So I'm supposed to create two bash scripts for the game "guess my number." One script is for Dealer while the other one is for Player.

Each script should wait for the other to generate their response (via a file) before proceeding. So when the Player is started, it first needs to wait for a response from the Dealer. When it detects it, the player gets the Dealer's response and processes it. When the Player makes a guess, the Player communicates that to the Dealer via a file.

While the Player is making a guess, the Dealer is waiting for the Player's response (via a file). When the Dealer detects it, the Dealer gets the response from the file and proceeds.

Below is my bash script for executing "guess my number" in bash script, but this only works if it's one file.

Can someone show me how to split this into two scripts (player_response.bash dealer_response.bash) and make them communicate via files and run simultaneously depended on another to achieve the same result? Much help is appreciated it!

---

```
#!/bin/bash
# this program random numbers between 1 and 100. 
clear
echo "Hello, "${USER}
date;
guess=1
## Start loop of game here
while true; do
n1=$(( ( RANDOM % 100 ) +1 ))
echo -n "I'm think of a number between 1 and 100. Guess: "

while read n2; do
    if [[ $n2 -eq $n1 ]]; then
        break;
    else
        if [[ $n2 -gt $n1 ]]; then
            echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too high. Guess again: "
        elif [[ $n2 -lt $n1 ]]; then
            echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too low. Guess again: "
        fi
    fi
    guess=$(( $guess + 1 ))
done
echo
echo "Congratulations! You win!"
if [[ $guess == 1 ]]; then
    echo "It took you $guess guess to get $n1."
else
    echo "It took you $guess guesses to get $n1."
fi
echo

read -p "Do you want to try again (y/n)? " choice
case $choice in
    [Yy]* ) guess=1;;
    [Nn]* ) exit;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
esac
## End loop of game here
done
```

Answer (score 4):

There are special files for that purpose (i.e. IPC) called [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). You can create them using the `mkfifo` command. The following is a very basic example based on your code. `dealer.sh` has to be executed first since it is responsible for creating and removing the named pipes.

**dealer.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

dealerResponse=dealerResponse
playerResponse=playerResponse

mkfifo $dealerResponse
mkfifo $playerResponse

# delete the named pipes on exit
trap "rm $playerResponse $dealerResponse" EXIT

guess=1
n1=$(( ( RANDOM % 100 ) +1 ))

# this blocks until the player has read from the pipe
echo -n "Please make a guess: " > $dealerResponse

while read n2 < $playerResponse; do
    if [[ $n2 -eq $n1 ]]; then
        echo You win! > $dealerResponse
        break
    else
        if [[ $n2 -gt $n1 ]]; then
            echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too high. Guess again: " > $dealerResponse
        elif [[ $n2 -lt $n1 ]]; then
            echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too low. Guess again: " > $dealerResponse
        fi
    fi
    guess=$(( $guess + 1 ))
done
```

**player.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

dealerResponse=dealerResponse
playerResponse=playerResponse

while true; do
    read line < $dealerResponse
    echo -n "$line "
    read guess
    echo $guess > $playerResponse
done
```

Comment: How do I make dealer.sh display output that shows:

- what the target number is
- what number attempt has been received by player
- the player's guess
- The success and total number of guesses played?

While the player.sh side shows:

- attempt number
- the guesses played
- how many tries it took the player to "Win the game"?

Comment: Target number is `$n1`, player's guess is `$n2`. You can use `echo` to print to stdout, e.g. `echo The target number is $n1`. You can use a `$guess` variable in player.sh like you did in your original code to count the number of guesses. This should be all you need to achieve your goal. If you encounter any problems, you can ask here (or probably better on stackoverflow), but we won't write your script for you.